# Why isn't the swipe gesture triggering a segue to the next view?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, segue

I've added a swipe gesture recognizer to a UICollectionView on storyboard, with a Navigation Controller set up. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u1-DGiUhXU), except I'm using an UICollectionView for the first view.

[image: Flow of storyboard]

The actual problem is that when I run the program, and I try to swipe, nothing happens. Everything else happens.

I have tried following the directions over and over and in different ways, but nothing seems to work. I've created another project and just using regular view, it worked fine, which makes me think that the UICollectionView is part of the problem. Am I putting the gesture recognizer in the wrong view? I've tried putting it in the UIView of the first View Controller and in the UICollectionView, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?
Clearly, if I left any information out or you need any information at all, please don't hesitate to ask in the comments for it.

**EDIT:** The connections of the swipe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you have define in storyboard, the segue from swipe gesture to next viewController ?
2. did you swipe in the correct direction (this can be set in storybord, select your swipe, attributes inspector, Right / Left / UP / Down

Comment: 1. Yes. I did this by CTRL dragging from the swipe icon in the black bar of the first view controller, to the view in the second and then hitting "Push". 2. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The `UICollectionView` Is probably taking the gesture over and telling the controller that It cannot handle the collection view gesture and your swipe gesture at the same time. Implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and return YES in this delegate method `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`. Make sure that the delegate of the swipe gesture is set on the controller from the storyboard.

Comment: It still happens the same way. Am I supposed to have the swiper on the UICollectionView, or the UIView that owns the UICollectionView?

Comment: The gesture should be on the view you want it on, and the delegate of the gesture should be to the controller